# Servlet init and Class

Tags: java, servlets, properties

I actually have a programm with a servlet :

```
@WebServlet("/Controler")
public class Controler extends HttpServlet {

}
```

I need to use a property file : `file.properties` in my program. To load it, I have a class :

```
public class PropLoader {

    private final static String m_propertyFileName = "file.properties";

    public static String getProperty(String a_key){

        String l_value = "";

        Properties l_properties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream l_input;
        try {

            l_input = new FileInputStream(m_propertyFileName); // File not found exception
            l_properties.load(l_input);

            l_value = l_properties.getProperty(a_key);

            l_input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return l_value;

    }

}
```

My property file is in the WebContent folder, and I can access it with :

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/file.properties");
```

But I can't call theses methods in another class than the servlet...

How can I access to my property file in the PropLoader class ?

Comment: Well, one option is to add the path as a static variable to the PropLoader class (kind of a singleton). I have seen cases where some main servlet makes these steps in the init() method, so you will have your path available on the whole application. You just have to be sure that the servlet you're dealing with get's loaded on application start.

Comment: I've tried this solution, but the servlet can't instantiate the path in the propLoader class, i think it's due to the init() servlet method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read the file from within the webapp structure, then you should use `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()`. And of course, since you load it from the webapp, you need a reference to the object representing the webapp: ServletContext. You can get such a reference by overriding `init()` in your servlet, calling `getServletConfig().getServletContext()`, and pass the servlet context to the method loading the file:

```
@WebServlet("/Controler")
public class Controler extends HttpServlet {
    private Properties properties;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        properties = PropLoader.load(getServletConfig().getServletContext());
    }
}

public class PropLoader {

    private final static String FILE_PATH = "/file.properties";

    public static Properties load(ServletContext context) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(context.getResourceAsStream(FILE_PATH));
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Note that some exceptions must be handled.

Another solution would be to put the file under `WEB-INF/classes` in the deployed webapp, and use the ClassLoader to load the file: `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.properties")`. This way, you don't need a reference to `ServletContext`.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet ! For your second solution, I copy/paste the result i've told to Icestari : My property file is in the Eclipse WebContent root folder, and `in == null` with : `InputStream in = Controler.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(m_propertyFileName); ` Then, I'm not sure to understand your first solution

Comment: That's why my answer tells you that, for this solution to work, the file must be under WEB-INF/classes. I'll edit my answer to make the first part clearer.

Comment: Same result with my property file in : `WEB-INF/classes/file.properties` or `WEB-INF/file.properties`, getResourceAsStream() returns null.

Comment: It must be under WEB-INF/classes in the *deployed* webapp (where the compiled .class files are). That means that it must be (if using a standard IDE) at the root of your source directory (where the source .java files are). And the path must be "/file.properties".

Comment: `getServletConfig()` part is unnecessary. The `init(ServletConfig)` has already prepared the `getServletContext()` beforehand.

Comment: @BalusC: Reading the javadoc, I have the feeling that init(ServletConfig) is a badly designed method, forcing the developer to call super(config), whereas the init() method without argument doesn't and still provides access to the config via a getter. Now of course, both will work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the getResourceAsStream method (example below). It would need that the properties file be at the WAR classpath.

```
InputStream in = YourServlet.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path_and_name);
```

Regards
Luan

Comment: Thanks for your answer Icestari ! My property file is in the Eclipse WebContent root folder, and `in == null` with : `InputStream in = Controler.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(m_propertyFileName);`